# How to display different content on the same page using different URLS

Tags: javascript

I using wordpress. I have query string functionally that displays the content in the correct language.

Example urls

```
example.com/privacy/?lang=en
example.com/privacy/?lang=es
example.com/privacy/?lang=fr
example.com/privacy/?lang=db
```

Code on `page-privacy.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">   
  var langCodeSearch = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  var langCode = Object.fromEntries(langCodeSearch.entries());

              
   Api.Initialized.then(function() {
    Api.LoadContent(["https://url-to-api-that-has-content.json"], langCode.lang //**language declaration need to happen here**);
              });
</script>
```

The above code works great but would it be possible to have the same functionally but using the following URL structure?

```
example.com/privacy/en
example.com/privacy/es
example.com/privacy/fr
example.com/privacy/gb
```

I want to display content based on the last part of the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a specific reason that you'd want to use query strings, but it sounds like maybe localization could cover your needs. That would allow for your content to be translated depending on the user's location.

I don't have too much experience with localization for WordPress specifically, but it looks like there's a ton of options as far as plugins that handle localization. Here's an article from one, TranslatePress, which explains the topic more in depth:

https://translatepress.com/wordpress-localization/

And the WordPress documentation on it:

https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/internationalization/localization/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).